# Closed Form Solution for Recurrence Relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

Is it possible to calculate the closed form solution for the following recurrence relation?

$$
T(n) = T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + T\left(\frac{n}{2} + 1\right) + \frac{n}{2}
$$

I am trying to teach myself about this stuff, and I see that it is similar in form to

$$
T(n) = \alpha T\left(\frac{n}{b}\right) + f(n)
$$

But the second term of $T\left(\frac{n}{2} + 1\right) $ is messing me up.

Comment: For which values of $n$ do you want $T(n)$ to be defined?

Comment: For all even integers greater than 1.

Comment: But each recursion relation for n even calls for some value T(2k+1)... You ought to make the model more precise before there is a real question here.

Comment: @lsowen: $T(2)=T(1)+T(2)+1$ is going to give you some headaches, then. Or $T(4)=T(2)+T(3)+2$, if $T(2)$ is given by an initial condition.

Answer (score 2):

For $n=0$, this yields $T(0)=T(0)+T(1)$. For $n=2$, this yields $T(2)=T(1)+T(2)+1$. Thus $T(1)=0=T(1)+1$, which might be seen as a problem.